# Take a mysql value and insert it into another table?

Tags: mysql

This a fairly straightforward issue.

I have a value in a MySQL table that I need to grab and place into a new table. I should also say that this will not denormalize my table as the value being pulled is in a temporary table/row etc.

In any case, this is an example of an attempt I made to do so:

```
INSERT INTO checkIn(t_id, p_id, checkIn, checkedOut) VALUES(2,11,curdate(), (SELECT checkedTime FROM checkOut WHERE t_id = 2));
```

As one can see, the value I'm trying to pull from the other table is denoted by the `SELECT` statement. When it is executed, only the `SELECT` statement is run - not the insert. Personally, I don't feel that this is the correct approach to accomplish my goal.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use values... do a straight insert like..

```
insert into myTable (someNum, someOtherNum, date, someTime) select 2, 11, curdate(), checkedTime  from checkout etc. etc.
```

Comment: Really? What is the reasoning behind that?

Comment: If I could tell you the reasoning behind why SQL works as it does, I'd already have written my own DB! :)

Comment: That's awesome! Ok, I'll try it then.

Comment: basically the idea is that you can select any value from a table... meaning, if you wanted to get the number 2 from any table, you can, so I know it looks kind of goofy, like you're selecting curdate from a table which has no such column, but the syntax allows you to do that, as well as also select things that actually ARE in that table.